# CalendarContract sometimes returns null values

Tags: null, calendar, cursor, calendarcontract

I have a problem with calendar cursor. Sometimes, when querying data for a calendar events, attendees or simply calendar details, the cursor returns null values.

**Example**

**Declare Calendar Attendee Cursor**

```
val projection = arrayOf(
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_ID, 
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EVENT_ID,
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, 
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL,
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, 
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE,
CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS)
val attendeesCursor = 
context.contentResolver.query(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, 
        projection, 
        CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID + "=?", 
        arrayOf(eventId.toString()), // eventiId is sent as param
        null
)
if (attendeesCursor != null && attendeesCursor.isBeforeFirst) {
    attendeesCursor.moveToFirst()
}
return attendeesCursor
```

**Provide Attendees Details**

```
                val attendee = EventAttendee(
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_ID)),
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EVENT_ID)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME)) ?,
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL)),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP)),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE)),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS))
            )
```

Sometimes, some of the Attendee details are null... I don't 
know why...

How is that possible? How to avoid this?

Comment: Please attach more relevant code to this so we can see what is actually going on. For instance the declaration of the cursor object among other things.

Comment: I provided the code. I hope you'll see it and 'll help me. Thank you!

Comment: Which language is this? It would seem that there is not always content where you think there should be content. What is content, contentResolver and projection?

Comment: It is kotlin language. It is from Android library. **ContentResolver** -
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html.  **Projection** - projection is an array of columns that should be included for each row retrieved.